# How to guarantee a class is never exposed client side with Vaadin

Tags: javascript, java, jakarta-ee, vaadin, vaadin7

I understand that Vaadin uses some logic to only expose the UI code and then calls the server to access the code through Javascript. However let's say I have a `Listener` for example with some code that references other classes. So let's say I have something like:

```
PojoClass data = DatabaseClass.getDataFromDatabase();
doSomeProcessingOnData(data);
..
myTextField.setValue(data.getSomeValue());
..
```

Now how I can be sure that the code behind `DatabaseClass` is not exposed as Javascript. I assume this just happens, but more specifically how can say the `doSomeProcessingOnData(data)` method which may have calls to say 4-5 different classes that has some internal IP property not be exposed? I understand `PojoClass` will be exposed but I don't want the internals of `doSomeProcessingOnData(data)` to be exposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Business Logic Stays On Server-Side

The business logic of your Vaadin app remains on the server-side in pure Java.   So no risk of exposure.

Vaadin remotes the user-interface to the client.

For example, when a button is clicked, a signal is sent by the client-side JavaScript library to the server to run the ClickListener code *on the server*. If that server-side Java code causes changes to the state of the user interface widgets, then Vaadin relays those widget state changes to the client’s JavaScript library for visual updating to the user. The **client-side remains blissfully unaware** that your server-side Java code connected to a database, called on a web service, opened a socket connection to a data feed, made some accounting calculations resulting in a new "Grand Total" value, posted a message to a queue, sent out an email, and wrote entries into an audit trail. All the client-side knows is: "button clicked" --> "Grand Total textField has new value to display".

Think of [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home) as the web’s version of [XWindows](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System).

Comment: So the TextField is basically pushed up to the client from the server if I'm reading that correctly because the client has no idea that there is a change to the TextField in the Listener class on the server side. Is that right?

Comment: Once displayed, the TextField already exists on the client-side, and remains there until removed by your code. When you set a new value of the content property of the TextField, Vaadin automatically takes note. When your ClickListener Java code completes its execution, Vaadin automatically updates the client-side widgets with all their noted state changes, including that TextField. A new TextField is *not* sent to client, merely an instruction to update the existing TextField's content property value. This makes Vaadin visually stable for the user and surprisingly quick.

Comment: I was struggling to understand how the TextField component knew to update itself. That completely makes sense, and that's actually what I was missing. Thank you very much, that really helped!